# When in Wordpress I try to run a php script directly I am redirected to the home page

Tags: plugins

http://my_domain/path_to_my_script/my_php_script.php

When I try to run my_php_script.php directly over the Internet giving the path above in my browser, I am being redirected to the home page of Wordpress.

Why that situation happens?

I've commented all the lines in the .htaccess file which can be found in the root Wordpress in order to see if the problem is in that file, but the situation gets worse - I got 500 Internal Server Error when I try to access that php file over the Internet.

I am using that script in ajax requests.

Could you plese give me some directions on how I could solve that problem.

Answer (score 0):

To use an external script with ajax, you must register an action to trigger it. To do it, you need to use wp_ajax_YourAction and wp_ajax_nopriv_YourAction

```
add_action('wp_ajax_YourAction', 'myAjaxFunction');
// just a way to quickly print your js
add_action('wp_head', 'print_js');

function print_js(){
    ?><script type="text/javascript" >
            jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
                var data = {
                        action: 'YourAction',
                        fun: '42',

                    };
                $.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
                        console.log(response);
                        var json = $.parseJSON(response);

                        alert('the fun number is'+response.fun);

                });
            });
    </script><?php
}
function myAjaxFunction(){
    if(isset($_POST['fun'])){
        $action = $_POST['fun'];
    }

    switch ($action) {

        case 'fun':
            echo json_encode(array('fun'=>$_POST['fun']+1))
            exit();
        break;

        default:
        break;
}
```

Depending on how your want to trigger your ajax call and the datas you want to post, this is just a simple example.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! Your solution is a standard one for WordPress ajax but my idea is a little bit different.

Comment: Maybe you can get your solution with a call made like an api call with wp_remote_get, wp_remote_post, process the data and work with the response with wp_remote_retrieve_body. But it's not an Ajax way

Comment: My idea is the following.
I am trying to load a php script using an ajax request, not to process some data passed as get() or post() request in a php script but to load the php script using JS. Because I am restricted to use JS, my only option is to use ajax. In a standard ajax application, which doesn't use any framework like WP the solution is like this $('.some_div_container').load('script.php',...), or .get(), or .post()
Is there a way in WP so that I can load a php script in that way?

Comment: sorry, unconsciously I pressed the ENTER key!

Comment: Can you edit your answer with some code. 500 errors can be easy to find with some of your code.

Comment: $.get( pathVar.testFirst, function(response) {
 $('.form-table').html(response);
 // alert( "Load was performed!" );
});
pathVar and testFirst are set by wp_localize_script();

Comment: wp_localize_script('load-player-test-switch', 'pathVar', array(
   'testFirst' => plugins_url('../../includes/player_tests/test1.php', __FILE__),
  ));

Comment: plugins_url('../../includes/player_tests/test1.php', FILE), )); YOU CAN NOT DO THIS ! Put your file directly in your plugin folder, the plugin_url function can not do such a thing.

Comment: as you can see I have set the first test test1.php as testFirst and I am accessing through the pathVar, but the problem is that it doesnt work, the reason is that the test1.php is not accessible through the Internet, WP somehow restricts the access to the .php files. If is is a .html file it works fine. That was the reason I opened this topic.

Comment: it is in the plugin folder actually
my_plugin/includes/player_tests/test1.php
in this folder are placed all the tests - 1,2,3...

Comment: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/plugins_url, FILE must be __FILE__ and the $path become relative from the file where the function is call. There is other WordPress function to do this, plugin_dir_url(), plugin_dir_path(), plugin_basename(). But I can tell you more about your plugin file structure, that I don't know.

Comment: Sorry, underscore for FILE don't appear... That was your case too :-)